# Conditional behaviour using dropdownlist and gui textbox in AHK

Tags: c++, autohotkey

Let's say I pick "Option1" and "Color1". Then I write something into the free text area. Now when I press OK it will do the conditional tags. Since Option1/color1 is picked, it will do a sendinput command with:

> blablala %text1% blabla %text2%.

If I however pick "option1" and "color" it will do a sendinput with

> blabla with his wife and her wife text1 then the dog did text2.

I've managed todo part of this code. My problem is that when I pick from the droplists, it executes the script no matter what I wrote. I want it to execute upon clicking OK and showing text1/text2 whereever I want to put it.

```
#NoEnv
Gui, 1: font, s10 , Verdana
Gui, 1: Add, DropDownList, gDropDownList vDropDownList1 R2 choose1, Option1|Option2
Gui, 1: Add, DropDownList, gDropDownList vDropDownList2 R2 choose1, Color1|Color2
Gui, 1:Add, text,, Text1
Gui, 1:Add, edit, vText1
Gui, 1:Add, text,, Text2
Gui, 1:Add, edit, vText2
Return

DropDownList: 
Gui, 1:Submit,NoHide
if (dropdownlist1 = "Option1") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color1")
{
    MsgBox, A flower said to a be: %text1%. The bee replied %text2%
    Gui 1: hide
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option1") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color2")
{    
    MsgBox, You picked %text1% and %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option2") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color1")
{    
    MsgBox, A girl said %text1% when you picked %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option2") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color2")
{    
    MsgBox, Blabla %text1% blabla %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
return

#j::
Gui 1: show,, DropDownGui
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've managed todo part of this code. My problem is that when I pick
>   from the droplists, it executes the script no matter what I wrote.

That's because you have a gosub attached to your drop down list. That's what the `g` in `gDropDownList` is. When you select something from that, it runs the DropDownList label.

You can either completely remove the `gDropDownList` from the options field, or you could make a label that saves your selections on click by making a gui submit label.

Try something like this:

```
#NoEnv
Gui, 1:font, s10 , Verdana
Gui, 1:Add, DropDownList, gGuiSave vDropDownList1 R2 choose1, Option1|Option2
Gui, 1:Add, DropDownList, gGuiSave vDropDownList2 R2 choose1, Color1|Color2
Gui, 1:Add, text,, Text1
Gui, 1:Add, edit, vText1
Gui, 1:Add, text,, Text2
Gui, 1:Add, edit, vText2
Return

GuiSave:
    Gui, 1:Submit,NoHide
return

DropDownList: 
Gui, 1:Submit,NoHide
if (dropdownlist1 = "Option1") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color1")
{
    MsgBox, A flower said to a be: %text1%. The bee replied %text2%
    Gui 1: hide
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option1") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color2")
{    
    MsgBox, You picked %text1% and %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option2") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color1")
{    
    MsgBox, A girl said %text1% when you picked %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
else if (dropdownlist1 = "Option2") && (dropdownlist2 = "Color2")
{    
    MsgBox, Blabla %text1% blabla %text2%
    Gui 1: hide 
}
return

#j::
Gui 1: show,, DropDownGui
return
```